# Column value as index to generate 2 level collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, indexing, group-by, eloquent

I am trying to get a collection which has index as column values.
First level will have `product_id` as index and second level will have `stock_date`.

```
$data = Model::select('column1', 'product_id', 'stock_date')
                         ->where('some condition')
                         ->get();

$data = collect($data)->groupBy('product_id');
```

With the code above, I get the collection with `product_id` as the indexes.

I need the data of each product indexed by `stock_date`

If, for example, for `product_id` - `1`, I have multiple records, I tried

```
$product_details = collect($data[1])->groupBy('stock_date');
```

But it does not index the records with `stock_date` further.

Need help to index them with `stock_date`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you means these records are nested by stock_date,

and then stock_dates are nested by product_id

If it is, please try this below, the `collect()` method make all nested records becomes collection, you don't need to use `collect()` again.

```
$data = Model::select('column1', 'product_id', 'stock_date')
                     ->where('some condition')
                     ->get();

$data = collect($data)->groupBy('product_id');

$nested_products = [];
foreach($data as $product_id => $items) {
    $nested_products []= $items->groupBy('stock_date');
}
```

Or you can try this line, it's more elegant:

```
collect($data)->groupBy('product_id')->transform(function($item, $k) { return $item->groupBy('stock_date');})
```

Comment: I had tested this code, and it works. Does it any other problem?

Comment: I add a new code and it works fine too, this will be more simple

Comment: Actually now i got my collect()->groupBy() working :( thanks for your help :) unable to delete question

Answer (score 1):

possible solution.

```
// first index grouped by product_id
$original = Model::select('column1', 'product_id', 'stock_date')
                         ->where('some condition')
                         ->get()
                         ->groupBy->product_id;

$final = collect();

// iterate through each group and
// group inner collection with 'stock_date'
// and put them back in an collecion
foreach($original as $key => $value) {

    $final->put($key, $value->groupBy->stock_date);

}
```

Comment: Actually now i got my collect()->groupBy() working :( thanks for your help :) unable to delete question